# Communicate with android activity in a normal java class

Tags: android

Dear all
  I have an android activity and a normal .java class which contains an "onChange" function(the function is called whenever properties of my skype contact are changed)

When I try to call an alertdialog.show() in my onChange function, I got error "Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()", what should I do to show a message in my activity? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
class LooperThread extends Thread {
      public Handler mHandler;
      
      public void run() {
          Looper.prepare();
          
          mHandler = new Handler() {
              public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                  // process incoming messages here
              }
          };
          
          Looper.loop();
      }
  }
```

[From the android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html) :

Threads by default do not have a message loop associated with them; to create one, **call prepare() in the thread that is to run the loop**, and then loop() to have it process messages until the loop is stopped

*Also never ever have UI calls in a (worker) Thread. It is bound to throw exceptions.*